# How to use Router in React-Context?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to login and stay on same page after refresh in reactjs, I was go through this website an started developing a small project  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/state-management-with-react-hooks/

on successful login dispatch a type login but I found one issue if we refresh he page after entering in home it return to old page i.e. `<Login />` do not stay on`<Home />`

I think I need to wrap this inside of Router as I am a beginner and learning reactjs, I a not able todo that

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Header from "./components/Header";
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: null,
  token: null,
};
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(action.payload.user));
      localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(action.payload.token));
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: action.payload.user,
        token: action.payload.token
      };
    case "LOGOUT":
      localStorage.clear();
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: null
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        state,
        dispatch
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">{!state.isAuthenticated ? <Login /> : <Home />}</div>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page it runs all the js code again. Therefore, every refresh you are initialise your store with the empty initial state where `user=null` and `token=null`.

In order to persist across refresh you have to get `user` and `token` back out of localstorage and use it as your initial state if they exist.

Here's a simple solution that doesn't handle errors or invalid tokens:

```js
function getInitialState() {
 const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
 const user = localStorage.getItem("user")

 if (token && user) {
  return {
   isAuthenticated: true,
   user,
   token
  }
 };

 return {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: null,
  token: null,
 };
}
```

Comment: Hi @Will Don't I need to use routing in this as my url  also remain same?

Comment: Do you have an idea how to store httponly cookie so that its not visible to client as localStorage as its not safe to store token

Comment: Hi @ParthTiwari, you can look into using something like react-router for routing if you need it. It will let you initialize your js app based on the current url .

Comment: You should probably ask another question regarding tokens. Take a look at JSON Web Tokens as they might solve your use case.

Comment: Hi @Will I want to use router so based on url it will load the page

Comment: Checkout react-router, it's great and has great documentation.

Comment: hi @Will where should I place yours code in mine code